# context=this make my applications stop working

Tags: java, android

That `context=this` makes my applications stop working. What's wrong?

```
package com.robot.soccer.control;
import com.robot.soccer.control.R;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AccelerometerListener {

TextView ipText;
 TextView portText;
 TextView status;
 TextView xStatus;
 TextView yStatus;
 TextView zStatus;
 TextView accText;

 ImageButton goBut;
 ImageButton kickBut;
 public float xVal;
 public float yVal;

private static Context CONTEXT;
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        accText=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.accm);
        xStatus=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.x);
        yStatus=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.y);
        zStatus=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.z);
        status=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.status);
        portText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.portText);
        ipText=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.ipText);
        goBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.goBut);
        kickBut=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.kickBut);
        goBut.setOnClickListener(this);
        kickBut.setOnClickListener(this);
        accText.setText("AccelerometerStatus ");
        //CONTEXT=this;

    }
```

Here's my logcat:

```
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.IVibratorService$Stub$Proxy.vibrate(IVibratorService.java:106)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Vibrator.vibrate(Vibrator.java:44)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.robot.soccer.control.Main.vibrate(Main.java:253)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.robot.soccer.control.Main.OnAccelerationChanged(Main.java:239)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.robot.soccer.control.AccelerometerManager$1.onSensorChanged(AccelerometerManager.java:135)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:449)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-20 01:22:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Assigning the variable probably does nothing by itself. What are you doing with `CONTEXT`?

Comment: first remove static from Context variable as `private Context CONTEXT;` and post  log also when you app is crashing

Comment: There is nothing that prevents him from using the static modifier other than that it's probably a bad design choice. :P

Comment: oke,,, edited whit logcat.. check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your logcat result says :

> java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission 12-20

means you need to add VIBRATE permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: @YoGhiShicibukai : most welcome friend !!! :) and one suggestion avoid to use of static fields or behavior in android application as much as possible try to use inbuilt api's

Answer (score 2):

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

Add the VIBRATE permission to your manifest.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#VIBRATE

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`